# out to do something -- meaning?

Tags: meaning

Example with a context ([Murders of pro-Russian lobbyists increase tension in Ukraine standoff](http://news.yahoo.com/ukrainian-journalist-killed-masked-gunmen-kiev-interior-ministry-113439690.html)):

> Ukrainian officials and political analysts suggested they were the work of Russian special forces assassins **out to blacken** the image of Kiev's pro-Western authorities.

How do you understand the expression *to be out to do something*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check [***out to***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/out+to)

"fixed on a purpose", "resolute", or "determined" would have a similar meaning.

Answer (score 3):

I think that means they have the intention of doing something, or are intent on doing something.

Comment: Welcome to ELL Stack Exchange! That's a pretty good first answer. If you stick around you'll get a lot of well-intentioned advice. Here's your first piece: This answer sounds a lot like unfounded opinion, even though it looks right. It would help to add some kind of supporting evidence, whether it's just a reference to personal experience, a dictionary entry, or something else.

Comment: @DCShannon Thanks for the welcome and the advice, I'll try to do better next time :). I won't edit the answer, though, because someone else already answered correctly.